# Is it possible to memcache a json result in App Engine?

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

I think my question is already clear enough, but to make it even more clear i will illustrate it with my example.

I'm currently returning many json every request, which I would like to cache in some way. I thought memcache would be great, but I only see that they use memcache for caching queries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSON is just text, so yes, you can store it in memcache.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. Maybe could have found out by trying.